# Turn array value into a variable

Tags: php, arrays

I does anyone know how I make an make a variable from an array?

For example:

I am trying to echo the state abbreviation from the below array. The $state value is actually a state like New York. But I want to echo the state abbreviation after the array.

```
$state = $guest_state;
echo convert_state($state);

  function convert_state($key) {
  $a2s = array( 
   'AL'=>'Alabama',
'AK'=>'Alaska',
'AZ'=>'Arizona',
'AR'=>'Arkansas',
'CA'=>'California',
'CO'=>'Colorado',
'CT'=>'Connecticut',
'DE'=>'Delaware',
'DC'=>'District of Columbia',
'FL'=>'Florida',
'GA'=>'Georgia',
'HI'=>'Hawaii',
'ID'=>'Idaho',
'IL'=>'Illinois',
'IN'=>'Indiana',
'IA'=>'Iowa',
'KS'=>'Kansas',
'KY'=>'Kentucky',
'LA'=>'Louisiana',
'ME'=>'Maine',
'MD'=>'Maryland',
'MA'=>'Massachusetts',
'MI'=>'Michigan',
'MN'=>'Minnesota',
'MS'=>'Mississippi',
'MO'=>'Missouri',
'MT'=>'Montana',
'NE'=>'Nebraska',
'NV'=>'Nevada',
'NH'=>'New Hampshire',
'NJ'=>'New Jersey',
'NM'=>'New Mexico',
'NY'=>'New York',
'NC'=>'North Carolina',
'ND'=>'North Dakota',
'OH'=>'Ohio',
'OK'=>'Oklahoma',
'OR'=>'Oregon',
'PA'=>'Pennsylvania',
'RI'=>'Rhode Island',
'SC'=>'South Carolina',
'SD'=>'South Dakota',
'TN'=>'Tennessee',
'TX'=>'Texas',
'UT'=>'Utah',
'VT'=>'Vermont',
'VA'=>'Virginia',
'WA'=>'Washington',
'WV'=>'West Virginia',
'WI'=>'Wisconsin',
'WY'=>'Wyoming',
   );
   $array = (strlen($key) == 2 ? $a2s : array_flip($a2s));
   return $array[$key];
 }
```

Comment: "a variable from an array" -- it's a variable already

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: `array_search('New York', $a2s);`?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `array_filter()`

```
$array; // your array
$needle; // the state you are looking for
$filtered_array = array_filter($array, function ($element) use ($needle) {
    return ($element['state'] === $needle);
});

$matching_keys = array_keys($filtered_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array array_keys ( array $array [, mixed $search_value = NULL [, bool $strict = false ]] )
```

array_keys() returns the keys, numeric and string, from the array.

If the optional search_value is specified, then only the keys for that value are returned. Otherwise, all the keys from the array are returned.

So this should do your thing:

```
array_keys($a2s, $key);
```

Answer (score 0):

function convert_state($state) {

```
 $a2s = array() // Lets pretend this is the exact copy of yours, i didn't want to type it out.
 foreach ($a2s as $stateAbbrv => $stateName) {
      if (strtolower($stateName) === strtolower($state)) {
           echo $stateAbbrv;
      }
 }
```

};

So you'll be iterating through the $a2s until you find a match with your $stat parameter, then it will out put the key.

Comment: Thanks did worked.  Any idea why I cant echo 

echo $stateAbbrv;   where ever I want within my code?  It only displays if I echo the variable right after the script     
 foreach ($a2s as $stateAbbrv => $stateName) {
      if (strtolower($stateName) === strtolower($state)) {

echo $stateAbbrv;

Comment: if you are trying to echo the abbreviation, then it's just echo array_search(strtolower($state), array_map('strtolower', $a2s));  strtolower is used because you want to lower case all the comparisons, so it doesn't fail on Wisconsin and wisconsin.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as:

```
return array_search($key, $a2s);
```